# Does multiple assignment make may code slower?

Tags: python, python-2.7, time, variable-assignment, timeit

My question is a simple one. Does using multiple assignments make the code slower ? (Even if it is slower, is it worth considering ? )

I need performance for my code. This assignment is in a loop that will possibly be executed many times.

I made a quick check of things. And I am not exactly sure how to analyse these results or what conclusion I should derive from them. Let me put those here for you.

```
import timeit
print(timeit.timeit("a = 1; b = 2", number=100000))
print(timeit.timeit("a = 1; b = 2", number=100000))
print(timeit.timeit("a = 1; b = 2", number=100000))

print

print(timeit.timeit("a, b = (1, 2)", number=100000))
print(timeit.timeit("a, b = (1, 2)", number=100000))
print(timeit.timeit("a, b = (1, 2)", number=100000))

print

print(timeit.timeit("a = (1, 2) ;b =a[0] ;c = a[1]", number=100000))
print(timeit.timeit("a = (1, 2) ;b =a[0] ;c = a[1] ", number=100000))
print(timeit.timeit("a = (1, 2) ;b =a[0] ;c = a[1] ", number=100000))
```

**Gives:**

```
0.00271645813545
0.00316250124554
0.00289307923274

0.00323691303956
0.00329421867402
0.00343021264239

0.011346943279
0.0154434408356
0.0141857104552
```

I ran it several times and this was the overall result.

There appears a slight difference (except creating tuple first, which was already obvious, just wanted to see.), what should I conclude from this?

Comment: well, are you writing code for a facebook/google-sized operation where 0.00000008 seconds per assignment would be a dealbreaker?

Comment: Well if I adopt some tecnique, I will possibly use it thoughout the code. When coupled with high cpu requiring problems, this could be something that one should consider. I wanted to **learn.**

Comment: Why did you spend the time getting results you didn't know what you were going to do with? Have you tried profiling the application, rather than microoptimising something that may be irrelevant?

Comment: So shouldn't have I got the results in the first place? I knew what I was going to do with it. I needed some guidance in making more correct decisions.

Comment: you're worrying about a microscopic fraction of time. If this code only ever executes once, it's irrelevant how efficient it is. you'll have wasted 99% of your time optimizing something that's completely useless to optimize in the first place. optimize critical sections of the code - places where saving 0.0000000008 seconds WILL make a difference.

Comment: This is in the main loop of an algorithm where it will used in every step of solving this cpu consuming question. Thanks for the advices.

Comment: You can conclude that you would have had to do 22 billion assignments to make up for the 30 minutes this question has been up here, and that you should not be using performance to choose one syntax above the other.

Answer (score 1):

This specific question is answered along with some discussion points here:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed (They assert that yes, multiple assignment is slower, except when used for a swap.)

I eliminated the creation of the tuple by running this:

```
import timeit
print (timeit.timeit("i=(1,2); a=1; b=2", number=1000000))
print (timeit.timeit("i=(1,2); a, b = i", number=1000000))
```

The difference seemed to be significantly more than some here suggest, but when I reverse the order that they get timed, the first timeit seemed to run slower.  Sometimes it was slow enough that it took longer to assign twice, rather than multiple assign a tuple. I conclude that this testing mechanism is flawed.

Multiple assignment is slower, so if you're doing multiple assignments in a loop, then it can add up. But you would have to be doing it A LOT, and that suggests there is probably a better way. To actually improve your code's performance, 1) profile it and figure out what actually is taking too long. 2) analyze the algorithm to find things you could do much better.

The profiler may actually agree with you and say this loop is too slow, but usually when a human tries to guess what's slow ... we get it wrong.  And then we waste days trying to fix something that's not actually slowing down the code, and end up with no change.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that multiple assignment is slower is because of the implicit tuple unpacking. Consider the following two functions:

```
def regular():
    a = 1
    b = 2

def multiple():
    a, b = 1, 2
```

The `dis` module can be used to see the corresponding bytecode.

```
from dis import dis

dis(regular)
#  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
#              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
#
#  3           6 LOAD_CONST               2 (2)
#              9 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
#             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
#             15 RETURN_VALUE    

dis(multiple)
#  6           0 LOAD_CONST               3 ((1, 2))
#              3 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2               <-- This line here.
#              6 STORE_FAST               0 (a)
#              9 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
#             12 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
#             15 RETURN_VALUE
```

While `regular` has to `LOAD_CONST` once more, this is quicker than `UNPACK_SEQUENCE`.